# How to number nested li's in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, counter, nested-lists, html-lists

I try do number all links in a nested list, the number should go in the "data-nav-no" attribute, the result should be like this:

```
<ul class="mainNav">
    <li><a href="#startseite" data-nav-no="1">Startseite</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ueber-uns" data-nav-no="2">Über uns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#leistungen" data-nav-no="3">Leistungen</a>
        <ul class="subNav">
            <li><a href="#langfristige-unterstuetzung" data-nav-no="4">Langfristige Unterstützung</a></li>
            <li><a href="#punktuelle-unterstuetzung" data-nav-no="5">Punktuelle Unterstützung</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#referenzen" data-nav-no="6">Referenzen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news" data-nav-no="7">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#kontakt" data-nav-no="8">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried this:

```
$("ul.mainNav li, ul.subNav li").each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();    
    $(this).children("a").attr('data-nav-no',index);
});
```

Works, but in the second list level the number starts with "0" again. Any ideas to solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
$("ul.mainNav li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).children("a").attr('data-nav-no',i)
});
```

The selector `ul.mainNav li` is finding all `li`s that are descendants of `ul.mainNav`; which **includes** the elements matched by the selector `ul.subNav li`. This is why I've omitted the `ul.subNav li` selector from my example. If you want to **only** target the **children** of the `ul.mainNav` element, then you should use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) instead of the [descendant](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

```
$("ul.mainNav > li, ul.subNav > li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).children("a").attr('data-nav-no',i)
});
```

The [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index)  method you were using returns the position of the element relative to it's sibling elements, where-as the `index` parameter provided by [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) is the position of the element in the jQuery collection.

Answer (score 3):

A simple change will be enough:

```
$("ul.mainNav, ul.subNav").find("li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).children("a").attr('data-nav-no',index)
});
```

The important detail is that you don't want to try to compute the `index` yourself, but just use what `each` passes into your callback function.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/TNHj8/)** (the example changes the HTML to make the results visible).